# How to generate a number sequence 1111222233334444....9999...?

Tags: python, numbers, sequence

I want to generate **111122223333....** A sequence of numbers, each number appearing the same number of times, up to a certain number.

---

I use python for loop to generate the number sequence, but it cost too much time when the end number is 7000.

```py
import pandas as pd

startNum = 1
endNum = 7000
sequence = []
for i in range(endNum):  
   for j in range(endNum):
       sequence.append(i)
print(i)
```

So what should i do to reduce time, and get my sequence? no matter method, not include excel.Thanks!

I'd like to get the number sequcency 111122223333

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the sequence? A `generator` might be very useful here. I doubt the sequence generation takes *thaaat* long but the printing of sequence is the actual bottleneck.

Comment: @luk2302 he does not even print the sequence. and generating the list takes 3.8s on my rather beefy laptop...

Comment: You are absolutely correct, read the `print` incorrectly. The other points stand though... And yes, generating 50M entries will take *some* time.

Comment: I find i can do it in C++ in two minutes, but what about python?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what for but

```
endnum = 7
''.join([f"{str(i)*4}" for i in range(endnum)])

print(result)
```

result

```
0000111122223333444455556666
```

and it takes less then 1s with `endnum = 7000`

```
0:00:00.006550
```

Answer (score 0):

So your code is not really doing what you're asking, so I'll add a few comments on what your code does to understand where it's not working, and provide you with an answer that does what you want.

```
import pandas as pd

startNum = 1 
endNum = 7000
sequence = []
for i in range(endNum): # Here you are looping from 1 to endNum = 7000 
    for j in range(endNum): # Here you are looping from 1 to endNum = 7000
        sequence.append(i) # You are adding i (7000 times because of your previous loop)
print(i) # You probably mean to print sequence ?
```

You probably want the second loop to be run on the number of repeating characters that you want (which is 4).

Here's the code that does what you want:

```
startNum = 1
endNum = 7000
sequence = []
repeat = 4
for i in range(endNum):
    for _ in range(repeat):
        sequence.append(i)
print(sequence)
```

In your case, I'd prefer using extend and list comprehension (both codes are equivalent):

```
startNum = 1
endNum = 7000
sequence = []
repeat = 4
for i in range(endNum):
    sequence.extend([i for _ in range(repeat)])
```

Comment: yeah, you are right. I'd like to output the sequence. print(i) is wrong.  It runs svery fast. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
startNum = 1
endNum = 5 

seq = [ (str(i+1))*endNum for i in range(endNum) ]
print("".join(seq))
```

Comment: Thank you. The str operation actually computer quicker than num operation.